# Customizing FullCalender.io View and Styling in Angular

Tags: angular, calendar

In my project, I want to customize [Fullcalender.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular) at the component level.so I tried couple of different ways and found a way to customize only the CSS. For example, I want to remove the header section form the Fullcalender and add a custom-built section.anyone have an idea how to do that.or should I built one from a scratch. if so can anyone suggest a way to do that?. I also tried `ng-calender` but couldn't find a way to customize it

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/piyush_05/pen/xxxgaPX, it's in plain JS but can be helpful
Found angular example as well https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo